# How to make a file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I'm having trouble trying to get my file into a dictionary with multiple values

```
bench,103,222,32
table,833,99,23
chair,83,22,882
```

My code so far is

```
sol={}
infile= open("furniture.dat","r")
for line in infile:
     key,value=line.split(",")
```

I'm trying to get the words as keys and the number as the value for the dictionary, but receiving error on the split()

Comment: Based on your example file, the result of the `split` has more than two elements, so you can't just unpack into `key,value`.  You can use `key, *values = line.split(',')`, or if you don't like the unpacking syntax, something like `split=line.split(','); key, values = split[0], split[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on 0x5453's comment, try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
sol={}
infile= open("furniture.dat","r")
for line in infile:
     key,*value=line.rstrip().split(",")
     print(f"key = {key},  value = {value}") 
     sol[ key ] = value
```

I added the python3 shebang up top (since the unpacking feature is in python3 only I've observed just now) and the rstrip() to take the newline off of the last element.  I also left my debug code in there for you to review the results.

I've also added a line of code to populate your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Could you please explain the *value and how that prevent too many values error, so I could have a better understanding of the code

Comment: value is telling python to unpack a single value.  However, on the right side of the assignment, you have a list of more than 2 items.  The split() creates a list for each  comma separated sub-string in line (as you know).  So, once you have more than 2 items in that expression, the unpacking fails.  `*value` on the other hand, accepts all of the unpacked items.  Key gets the first item and value is assigned the remaining items.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `for line in infile` will read each line of the file as a string.

Secondly, you're getting an error because `split(",")` will separate the string into different items *wherever* there is a comma (","), and then return those items separately.

In your case, for the first line, it'll return `"Bench" "2750" "3000" "2880"`, which are 4 items, while you've only written the code to store them with 2 variables.

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```py
res = line.split(",")  # split returns list with items: ["Bench", "2750", "3000", "2880"]
key, value = res[0], res[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a proof of concept:

```
data = "Bench,2750,3000,2880 Chair,46,70,57 Table,147,152,150"
dic = {}
data = ",".join(data.split(" ")).split(",") #This gets rid of spaces,
#                                            puts commas there and than
#                                            splits everyting up again
print(data)
r,tmp = 1,[]
for i in data:
    if i[0].isalpha():
        if r == 1:
            temp = i
            r = 0
        else:
            dic[temp] = ",".join(tmp.copy())
            temp = i
            tmp.clear()
            r = 0
    else:
        r = 0
        tmp.append(i)
print(dic)
```

This code can be made a lot better, but this is what i came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [list splicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
my_dict = {}
with open('furniture.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line_list = line.split(',')
        new_dict = dict(zip(line_list, [(line_list[1:])]))
        my_dict.update(new_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

Output dictionary: `{'bench': ['103', '222', '32'], 'table': ['833', '99', '23'], 'chair': ['83', '22', '882']}`