# How do I fetch function parameters from a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

My assignment (have to use Turtle) asks me to draw three spirals using given parameters. The drawing function is fine, but now I need a function which gets the parameters from the text file.

Parameters in the text file:

```
black,20,10,3,1
red,10,20,4,3
blue,10,-20,-4,3
```

My drawing function is

```
def draw_spiral(color, arcs, initialradius, radiusgrowth, thickness):
    color(color)
    pensize(thickness)
    for i in range(arcs):
        growth = radiusgrowth * i
        circle(initialradius+radiusgrowth, 90)
```

What I have tried so far:

```
def draw_from_file(name):
   with open(name) as file:
```

and then I blank out, somehow I need to extract the right values from the text file to each parameter in the function draw_spiral.

Thanks a lot for your efforts and tips.

Comment: Similar question asked a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61508265/10629482

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

```
def draw_from_file(name):
   with open(name, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            new_args = line.split(',')
            draw_spiral(new_args[0], new_args[1], new_args[2], new_args[3], new_args[4])
```

There are more concise and pretty looking ways to do this, but that is the essence of it. Split the line on commas into a list and then feed the elements of that list into your `draw_spiral` function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def draw_from_file(name):
   with open(name, "r") as file:
       for line in file.read().splitlines():
           params = line.split(",") # split each line by comma to create list of values
           draw_spiral(*params)
```